Drawing complete great circle between two points in QGIS
I'm trying to use QGIS to project the great circle that connects two points. Many plugins exist to find the great circle distance or draw only the segment of the great circle, between two specified points, but I cannot find a way to draw the entire circle.
I suspect that the answer is closely related to this one, but that question relates to drawing a great circle given a point and an angle, rather than two points. (I know how to go from one to the other in Cartesian geometry, but not spherical.)

Great cirlce connecting Istanbul and New York and extending beyond, exported from QGIS as KML file and visualized in Google Earth. You can download the file from here.

The Great Circle passes through the two points, as well as through the antipodes of these two points (the points exactly opposite the globe - like north pole is antipode of south pole etc.). See here for a formula to calculate the coordinates of the antipode.
Make sure you have your two points on a layer in EPSG:4326. Then create a line connecting 1) Antipod of point B, 2) point A, 3) Point B, 4) Antipod of point A - see screenshot below. Use the following expression with Geoemtry by expression to create the line (here, point A has $id=5 and point B $id=6 - change this according to your values):
case
when $id=5
then
make_line (
    make_point (
        if (
            x<0, 
            x(geometry (get_feature_by_id ('points',$id+1)))+180, 
            x(geometry (get_feature_by_id ('points',$id+1)))-180
        ),
        -y (geometry (get_feature_by_id ('points',$id+1)))
    ),
    $geometry, 
    geometry (get_feature_by_id ('points',$id+1)),
    make_point (
        if (
            x<0, 
            x($geometry)+180, 
            x($geometry)-180
        ),
        -y ($geometry)
    )
)
end

Then Use Geodesic Densifier plugin as described in the other answer on the resulting line.
Black: straight line, created by the expression above. Red: Great circle, created with the plugin:

As you see, the line is still not closed completely over the antimeridian (+/-180 degrees E/W). To do so, split the created circle at your two points (manually or with this solution), extract the vertices and create the antipodes with this expression using Geometry by Expression:
make_point (
    if (
        x<0, 
        x($geometry)+180, 
        x($geometry)-180
    ),
    -y ($geometry)
)

Then connect the points with Points to path to get the remaining line. Copy this line and add (paste) it to the existing Great cirlce line created by the plugin. Don't bother about the straight line at the bottom, this is only due to the project CRS. If you export the line as KML (download it from here) and open it in Google Earth, you'll see that you indeed have a complete Great Circle line passing through your two initial points (2nd screenshot below).




Use Geodesic Densifier plugin. Use your line as input and make the settings accordingly, see screenshot for a line from Istanbul to New York: the red line is the great circle, the black line the inital, "flat" line on the projected canvas.


The question also mentions drawing the remaining part of the full great circle (for which I have not managed to find a suitable solution despite multiple attempts)

Yes, there are a number of plugins available if you only want the arc of great circle between the two points; it’s the projection that I’ve struggled with.

An easy way to create a great circle line, passing through two points with the help of only QGIS native tools, is using a Two-point equidistant projection, see here for details. In this projection, the great circle passing through these two points is a straight line.
Two-point equidistant projection with Istanbul and New York as the two points. The great circle corresponds to the red line:

Create a custom projection with the coordinates of your two points. I used Istanbul (41 N 29 E) and New York (40.7 N -74 W) with this Proj String definition:
+proj=tpeqd +lat_1=41 +lon_1=29 +lat_2=40.7 +lon_2=-74 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +R=6371000 +units=m +no_defs

When created, reproject your two points to this custom projection. Then use Geometry by expression with the following expression to create the Great Circle line (points is the name of your point layer):
densify_by_count( 
    extend(
        make_line (
            $geometry, 
            geometry (get_feature_by_id ('points', $id+1))
        ),
        12000000,
        12000000
    ), 
    1000
)


Use the shape digitizing toolbar


Romainbh: a Great Circle is something specific; https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Great_circle, not simply a circle from the Digitizing tool !

When I saw this question I first thought it was about making a circle from two points. But the question is about the Earth (geoid) and creating a line passing through two points on the geoid.

Thanks to this question, I discovered the existence of the great circle ;-) You have to learn something new every day!
